# mySQL getting excluded range of numbers

Tags: mysql, numbers, range

im trying my best to explain this,I have my first table, i have enter numbers to two columns COL1, COL2. in COL1 i enterd the starting range of the set of number, whereas in COL2 the end point in the number. So that I will have this data.

```
COL1     COL2
  1      100
101      200
201      300
```

The data above is read 1 to 100 (1-100), 101 to 200 (101 - 200), so on...

Now I have the second table which also contain a set of range numbers.

```
COL1     COL2
  1       50
 70      100
150      200
201      210
250      300
```

What I want to know is if it is possible to get the range of numbers not encoded in the 2nd table. like it should be in this result.

RESULT:

```
COL1     COL2
 51       69
101      149
211      249
```

The result shows the range of numbers not included in 2nd table which is supposed to be there since it is included in the range of numbers in the 1st table.
I dont know if its is possible with mySQL alone yet any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Although not essential, one way is to build a utility table of integers (0-9), join it to itself (twice), join table1 to get upper and lower bounds and (LEFT) OUTER JOIN table2 (WHERE NULL) to get the excluded values.